# Print multiple line inputs followed by string at once without waiting for "Enter" prompt

Tags: python

I need to write a simple program in Python that displays two user inputs on line 1 and 2 of the terminal, and then an output string on line 4 that updates after both inputs are entered. When the first input is entered, the cursor simply moves down to the second input, and all of the text below it must be visible. Once the second input is entered, the visible output string is simply updated, rather than printed on a new line. It will look similar to this:

[image: Line 1 reads Magical Flask Game Followed by an input to select the source flask on line 3, an input to select the "destination flask" on line 4, an error message on line 5 (if the inputs are invalid), and a multiline string displaying the current game state]

The inputs right now are called after the game state is printed, but the assignment requires that they are prompted at the same time as the game state is printed, and are intractable on their respective lines (put the input of the first one on its line and then the input of the second one one the next line).

The input functions look like this. I haven't done anything for the error line yet, so it just prints for now:

```
def origin_input():
    origin = input('Select the source flask: ')
    while not origin.isdigit():
        print('Invalid input.')
        origin = input('Select the source flask: ')

    origin = int(origin)

    if origin > FLASK_COUNT or origin < 1:
        print('Invalid input')

        return origin_input()
    
    return origin

def target_input(origin, flasks):
    target = input('Select the target flask: ')
    while not target.isdigit():
        print('Invalid input.')
        target = input('Select the target flask: ')

    target = int(target)
    if target > FLASK_COUNT or target < 1:
        print('Invalid input: Input out of range.')

        return target_input(origin, flasks)
    
    if target == origin:
        print('Target cannot be the same as the source.')
        return target_input(origin, flasks)
    
    if flasks[target - 1].sealed:  # accounts for 0 index
        print('Cannot pour into a sealed flask.')
        return target_input(origin, flasks)
    
    if flasks[target - 1].is_full():
        print('Target flask is full.')
        return target_input(origin, flasks)
    
    return target
```

The output string generator looks like this. It is still printing on a new line despite the `print(out_string, end='\r', flush=True)` at the end, so I'm still figuring out how to make that work as well:

```
def get_flask_str(flasks):
    print('\n')

    flask_list = []

    # generate flask strings
    for i, flask in enumerate(flasks):
        chem_str = '+--+' + f'\n  {i + 1} '
        for chem in flask.chemicals[::-1]:  # go backwards b/c the top is first in the list
            
            chem_str = f'|{chem}|\n' + chem_str

        if flask.sealed:
            chem_str = '+--+\n' + chem_str
            continue

        elif len(flask.chemicals) <= MAX_CHEM:  # only if flask is not completely full
            diff = MAX_CHEM - len(flask.chemicals) + 1  # account for extra space
            while diff > 0:
                chem_str = '|  |\n' + chem_str
                diff -= 1

        flask_list.append(chem_str)
        
    # concat multiline strings:
    lines_dict = {}

    for flask_string in flask_list:
        lines = flask_string.split('\n')
        for i, line in enumerate(lines):
            if i not in lines_dict:
                lines_dict[i] = [line]
            
            else:
                lines_dict[i].append(line)

    out_list = []
    for i in lines_dict:
        line = lines_dict[i]
        out_list.append('  '.join(line))

    out_string = ''
    for string in out_list[::-1]:  # flip right-side up
        out_string = string + f'\n{out_string}'
    
    print(out_string, end='\r', flush=True)
```

This is how the functions get called in the main function:

```
gameover = False
    while not gameover:  # no gameover clause for now
        get_flask_str(flasks)
        origin = origin_input()
        target = target_input(origin, flasks)

        oflask = flasks[origin - 1]
        tflask = flasks[target - 1]

        oflask.pour(tflask)
        if tflask.can_seal():
            print('Sealed target flask')  # temporary line
```

Here is a sample output as it is:

[image: The current game state is printed, followed by a prompt for the origin flask on the next line, then a prompt for the output flask on the line after, followed by a new line, and then the updated game state]

I tried using single input commands without any parameters but that clearly didn't work. I am not sure how to get around python waiting for the input to be entered before printing the next line.

Comment: Terminal I/O normally works in a purely top-to-bottom fashion.  Asking the user for input on a line *above* what has already been displayed would require `curses` or a similar library.  Or, make your program a GUI, rather than text-based at all.

Comment: I guess I should go learn `curses`

Comment: https://www.textualize.io/ will help you achieve that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I decided to go with: now in a real-world scenario, the better solution would be to simply use a GUI library like tkinter - however this project required the output to be in the terminal.

Using ANSI escape characters, one can use the `os` module to manipulate where the cursor is.

At the top of the program, initialize ANSI escape character in the terminal:

`os.system("")`

One can also define a dictionary of various ANSI escape characters:

```
ANSI = {
"RED": "\033[31m",
"GREEN": "\033[32m",
"BLUE": "\033[34m",
"HRED": "\033[41m",
"HGREEN": "\033[42m",
"HBLUE": "\033[44m",
"UNDERLINE": "\033[4m",
"RESET": "\033[0m",
"CLEARLINE": "\033[0K"
}
```

Then, define functions to clear the screen, print on certain x and y positions, and to move the cursor to a certain x and y position:

```
def cl():
    
    if os.name == "nt":  # windows
        os.system("cls")
    else:  # unix systems
        os.system("clear")

def loc_print(x, y, text):
    print (f"\033[{y};{x}H{text}")

def loc_cursor(x, y):
    print(f"\033[{y};{x}H", end='')
```

Now in my case, these three were enough to do what I needed to in the terminal. Please excuse my terrible code:

```
gameover = False
err_msg = ''
while not gameover:
    cl()
    game_state = get_flask_str(flasks)
    loc_print(0, 0, 'Magical Flask Game')
    loc_print(0, 3, 'Select source Flask: ')
    loc_print(0, 4, 'Select target Flask: ')
    loc_print(0, 5, err_msg)
    loc_print(0, 6, game_state)

    loc_cursor(22, 3)
    origin = input()

    err_msg = origin_valid(origin)
    if err_msg != '':
        continue

    origin = int(origin)
    cl()
    loc_print(0, 0, 'Magical Flask Game')
    loc_print(0, 3, f'Select source Flask: {origin}')
    loc_print(0, 4, 'Select target Flask: ')
    loc_print(0, 5, '')
    loc_print(0, 6, game_state)

    loc_cursor(22, 4)
    target = input()

    err_msg = target_valid(target, origin, flasks)
    while err_msg != '':

        cl()
        loc_print(0, 0, 'Magical Flask Game')
        loc_print(0, 3, f'Select source Flask: {origin}')
        loc_print(0, 4, 'Select target Flask: ')
        loc_print(0, 5, err_msg)
        loc_print(0, 6, game_state)

        loc_cursor(22, 4)
        target = input()
        err_msg = target_valid(target, origin, flasks)

    target = int(target)
        

    oflask = flasks[origin - 1]
    tflask = flasks[target - 1]

    oflask.pour(tflask)
    if tflask.can_seal():
        err_msg = 'Sealed target flask'

    if check_win(flasks):
        cl()
            
        game_state = get_flask_str(flasks)
        loc_print(0, 0, 'Magical Flask Game')
        loc_print(0, 3, f'Select source Flask: {origin}')
        loc_print(0, 4, f'Select target Flask: {target}')
        loc_print(0, 5, '')
        loc_print(0, 6, game_state)
        loc_print(0, 13, 'You Win')
        gameover = True
```

`The loc_cursor(x, y)` function changes the position of the cursor, and anything that is written on it as well. This code (although certainly in need of some cleanup) produces exactly what I needed.